# How to download multiple files simultaniously with wget?

Tags: wget, download

I am downloading ~330k scientific files with wget from a csv file containing the URLs of the files I need to download. So, I am using the command

```
wget -i all_the_urls.csv
```

and my file all_the_urls.csv looks something like this

```
http://dr16.sdss.org/sas/dr16/sdss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/11040/spec-11040-58456-0109.fits
http://dr16.sdss.org/sas/dr16/sdss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/11068/spec-11068-58488-0780.fits
http://dr16.sdss.org/sas/dr16/sdss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/11068/spec-11068-58488-0240.fits
...
```

The files are small, ~250 kB each. But their amount is so large that it would take days to download them with `wget`, if it is just one file after the other. Is there a wget command to use so that I can download multiple files simultaneously? Note - my question is not duplicate to many other about downloading many files from the same website. Also, please don't suggest me `wget2` - I am having some problems installing `wget2` and here I look for other solutions.

It might be relevant, that my internet connection is ~550 MB/sec and when the files are downloaded 1 by 1 their download speed is displayed as 150 kB/sec, which is minuscule in comparison. So regarding bandwidth it would make sense to download many files at once (at least I guess so)

Can you also tell me how to execute one of this potential alternatives:

- zip the files before I download them in the hopes that the single large zip file will be quicker to download
- the files that I am downloading are `.fits` and contain 3 tables. I actually need only the first table in each of them. So if I can make `wget` access and download only the first table (preferably append all the 1st table into one big file/table), then this might save time, too

Tnx for any suggestions or ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `parallel`. It's available in most Linux distros.

`-jN` means that N parallel programs will run. You can tune it to something like `-j8` or even more.

```
cat url-list | parallel -j8 wget {}
```

or alternatively

```
cat url-list | parallel -j8 wget ' ' {}
```

`cat` is reading the file with URLs to download. My file looked liked:

```
https://XXX/all/Packages/a/abrt-2.10.9-20.el8.x86_64.rpm
https://XXX/all/Packages/a/abrt-addon-vmcore-2.10.9-20.el8.x86_64.rpm
...
```

The output is then piped to parallel that is responsible for spinning multiple wgets (-jN decide how many). The `{}` is piped input line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately I get the error `/usr/bin/bash: wgethttp://dr16.sdss.org/sas/dr16/sdss/spectro/redux/v5_13_0/spectra/lite/9364/spec-9364-57699-0589.fits: No such file or directory`. I guess your answer needs to add a space between `wget` and the URL. I am right now looking how to do this, but if you know please share, too! If you do this and say in a sentence what `cat` is I can accept your answer :)

Comment: I'm quite sure that there is space beetween `wget` and `{}`.

Comment: For me I had to change your snippet `cat url-list | parallel -j8 wget ' ' {}` and then it worked like a charm. Strange. I accepted your answer and will include this alternative formulation in it. thanks again!

Comment: And also, do have an answer to my suggest alternative - if I can download in this manner not the full files from the URLs, but only the first table out of 3 in them?

Comment: Use `parallel -a url-list` to avoid UUOC.

Comment: My first thought when I saw this answer was also "that use of `cat` is useless", I would have used `parallel :::: url-list` to avoid though, but that's a matter of style.

Comment: @pLumo and Henrik, thanks for your comments, I will try them out, despite that the answer by Alex works also good!