# Download files in parallel with wget over a single connection

Tags: wget, gnu-parallel

This question is a follow-up to [How to download multiple files simultaniously with wget?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678915/how-to-download-multiple-files-simultaniously-with-wget)

Similar to that question, I need to download many files. With the accepted answer above recommends the use of `cat url-list | parallel -j8 wget {}`. But this will require establishing one TCP connection and also one https/TLS negotiation per URL, which is a waste on both client and server side.

If/Since all URLs are on the same server, they could be queried in multiple `GET /object.txt` over a single TCP / HTTPs connection.

Question: any way to do this with wget ?

Answer (score 5):

Wget does this by default (`--no-http-keep-alive` turns it off). If multiple successive URLs are on the same server, it reuses the same connection (assuming the server is willing).

You need to tell `parallel` to invoke wget fewer times. Pass `-X` to make it bunch the arguments in each invocation.

```
cat url-list | parallel -j8 -X wget
```